# Is it impossible to set NODE_PATH in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I used to work on my React app with ES6. By setting `NODE_PATH='src'`, I could import things by using path starting from `src` folder. Recently, I migrated to Typescript, and I figured out Typescript doesn't support NODE_PATH. After some research, I found NODE_PATH can be replaced with `baseUrl` in `tsconfig.json`. However, the way works and doesn't work sometimes.

I researched more, and some people said it's not officially possible, so I have use relative paths. Is it true that setting NODE_PATh thing is not allowed in Typescript and any other way for that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, the following way solved my issue. I got this solution from [this Github issue](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/issues/98#issuecomment-312935060).

**.env**

```
NODE_PATH=src
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "src",
    ...
  }
}
```